# Is it bad coding practice to redefine a predefined function?

Tags: python

In Python, you are able to redefine a predefined function such as assigning the predefined function `max` to equal 5, but is that bad practice? I am aware that it does work with no problems. I am just wondering is it is standard in industry.

```
max = 5
max(1, 2, 3)
print(max)
```

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: use `max_` or smt similar

Comment: Con: might lead to surprises, pro: elegant solution for some problems. In practice, you'd have to weigh the pros against the cons. There's no general answer to this question. At the very least, this will raise some eyebrows if it comes up in a code review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, redefining built-in functions like max in Python is generally considered bad practice for several reasons:

- Readability: It makes your code confusing for others (and for your
  future self) to read and understand. When built-in functions are
  redefined, anyone reading the code would expect the standard
  behavior, leading to misunderstandings.
- Maintainability: If the built-in function is used later in the code
  or in other modules, it may lead to unexpected behaviors or errors,
  making debugging and maintenance difficult.
- Compatibility: If your code is part of a larger project or if others
  use your code, redefining built-ins can lead to errors in other parts
  of the project that rely on the original functionality.

In your example, after assigning `max = 5`, `max` becomes an integer and loses its function identity. When you try to call `max(1, 2, 3)`, it results in a `TypeError` because `max` is no longer a function.

Instead, use different variable names to avoid shadowing built-in functions. This practice is more aligned with industry standards and contributes to cleaner, more maintainable code.

Comment: *"generally considered bad practice"* and *"This practice is more aligned with industry standards"* are just bold claims. Can you back them up with quotes or citations? While I don't disagree with your arguments, they are one-sided and claim a generality they may not have.